# mysql query creates duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT
  jos_vm_payment_method.payment_method_name `Payment method`, 
  CASE
    WHEN jos_vm_orders.ship_method_id LIKE '%1. luokka%' then '1. LK'
    WHEN jos_vm_orders.ship_method_id LIKE '%2. luokka%' then '2. lk'
    ELSE jos_vm_orders.ship_method_id
    END 'Postiluokka',
  CONCAT(first_name, SPACE(1),last_name) Nimi,
  address_1,
  zip,
  city,
  product_quantity, 
  order_item_sku,
  order_item_name,
  jos_vm_order_item.product_attribute, 
  jos_vm_order_item.order_id,
  jos_vm_orders.customer_note, 
  jos_vm_order_history.date_added,
  jos_vm_orders.order_status,   
  jos_vm_order_status.order_status_name,
  jos_vm_orders.order_total
FROM 
  jos_vm_order_payment,
  jos_vm_payment_method,
  jos_vm_user_info, 
  jos_vm_order_item,
  jos_vm_orders,
  jos_vm_order_history,
  jos_vm_order_status 
WHERE jos_vm_order_item.order_id >1450
  AND jos_vm_order_payment.payment_method_id = jos_vm_payment_method.payment_method_id
  AND jos_vm_user_info.user_info_id = jos_vm_order_item.user_info_id
  AND jos_vm_user_info.user_info_id = jos_vm_orders.user_info_id
  AND jos_vm_orders.order_id=jos_vm_order_history.order_id
  AND jos_vm_order_status.order_status_code = jos_vm_order_item.order_status
  AND jos_vm_orders.order_status NOT IN ("PO", "PO1", "PO2", "PE1", "PE2", "PE3",  "Z", "4", "2", "M", "H", "D", "S", "L", "B", "7", "X", "8", "5", "Y", "V")
GROUP BY jos_vm_order_item.order_item_id
ORDER BY jos_vm_order_item.order_id DESC
```

Problem: The Payment method has same value after query.

**Payment method**
id 1 Bank

id 2 Bank (But Should be Credit)

**

I can't figure out how the payment method would have unique value as everything else is having.

Please give me some advice.

UPDATE

#

**I did it ! !** :)

Thanks for hinting about JOINS!

```
SELECT 
  `jos_vm_orders`.`customer_note` Asiakasviesti,
  `jos_vm_payment_method`.`payment_method_name` `Maksutapa`,
  (CASE 
    WHEN `jos_vm_orders`.`ship_method_id` LIKE '%1. luokka%' then '1. LK'
    WHEN`jos_vm_orders`.`ship_method_id` LIKE '%2. luokka%' then  '2. lk' 
    ELSE `jos_vm_orders`.`ship_method_id`  END) `Postiluokka`,
  CONCAT(`jos_vm_order_user_info`.`first_name`, SPACE(1), `jos_vm_order_user_info`.`last_name`) `Nimi`, 
  `jos_vm_order_user_info`.`address_1` Osoite, 
  `jos_vm_order_user_info`.`zip` Postinumero, 
  `jos_vm_order_user_info`.`city` Kaupunki,
  `jos_vm_order_item`.`product_quantity` Kpl, 
  `jos_vm_order_item`.`order_item_sku` PakettiID,
  `jos_vm_order_item`.`order_item_name` Paketti,
  `jos_vm_order_item`.`product_attribute` Attribute,
  `jos_vm_order_payment`.`order_id`,
  `jos_vm_orders`.`order_total` 

FROM  
  `jos_vm_order_payment`
  INNER JOIN `jos_vm_payment_method` ON `jos_vm_payment_method`.`payment_method_id` = `jos_vm_order_payment`.`payment_method_id`
  INNER JOIN `jos_vm_orders` ON `jos_vm_order_payment`.`order_id` = `jos_vm_orders`.`order_id`
  INNER JOIN `jos_vm_order_user_info` ON `jos_vm_order_user_info`.`order_id` = `jos_vm_order_payment`.`order_id`
  INNER JOIN  `jos_vm_order_item` ON `jos_vm_order_item`.`order_id` = `jos_vm_order_payment`.`order_id`

WHERE `jos_vm_orders`.`order_id` >1450
ORDER BY `jos_vm_orders`.`order_id` DESC
```

Next I must study how this can be compressed so it is readable also later.

Comment: Argh my eyes! Code formatting for readability pls

Comment: also use JOIN for better readability

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Why would you expect this query to modify the value of payment method? What do you mean by `"how the payment method would have unique value as everything else is having"`?

Comment: Thanks for responses and Ed Gibbs for editing it readable. I will study joins and try. It is such a mess because I have one by one added things to the query. (to use them in MS Excel)

What I discovered is that if I add new group by I will get this:

Id1 Bank, Id1 Credit, Id2 Bank, Id2 Credit (four rows)

Comment: I did it! Thanks for pushing me niyou! Update added above.